# ASP.net Facebook ServerSide doesn't ACTUALLY Redirect

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Idea : I'm trying to simulate PHP invoking Javascript using ASP.net

```
$Dialog='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='.$Key.'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($Done);
echo'<script>top.location.href = "'.$Dialog.'";</script>';
```

Server Side Flow :

```
using System;
using System . Collections . Generic;
using System . Linq;
using System . Web;
using System . Web . UI;
using System . Web . UI . WebControls;
using System . Text;
using System . Security . Cryptography;
using System . Collections . Specialized;

namespace Facebook
{
    public partial class Default : System . Web . UI . Page
    {
        string Key = "397010480372609";
        string Value = "***************";
        string Permissions = "email,publish_actions,user_games_activity,friends_games_activity,publish_stream";

        string Done = "https://localhost:10010/Done.html";

        string Facebook = "https://www.facebook.com/";
        string Dialog = "dialog/oauth";

        protected void Page_Load ( object sender , EventArgs e )
        {
            Response . Redirect ( Facebook + Dialog + Query ( new NameValueCollection ( ) {
                { "client_id" , Key },
                { "redirect_uri" , Done }
                //{ "scope" , Permissions },
                //{ "state" , "" },
                //{ "response_type" , "code" }
                //{ "display" , "" }
            } ) );
        }

        private string Query ( NameValueCollection Collection )
        {
            return "?" + string . Join ( "&" , Array . ConvertAll ( Collection . AllKeys , Key => string . Format ( "{0}={1}" , HttpUtility . UrlEncode ( Key ) , HttpUtility . UrlEncode ( Collection [ Key ] ) ) ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Done.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Done</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Log :**

```
[12:26:04.454] POST https://apps.facebook.com/ajax/apps/usage_update.php?__s=1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 257ms]
[12:26:04.769] GET https://apps.facebook.com/_silverlight/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1029ms]
[12:26:05.314] POST https://localhost:10010/ [HTTP/1.1 302 Found 3ms]
---> [12:26:05.383] GET https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=397010480372609&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a10010%2fDone.html [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 501ms]
[12:26:05.677] GET https://apps.facebook.com/ai.php?ego=AT76ukhNGbYVnWIi7k_pBVSIqDPGVWMXGApNCp_ZP6E8Gr5I2sqK0UfQI7fZnW0YKD70p1B5odpyaBePTI4rmSnhnyR3mI2WdPsZPQ43jeegdD77MOL7ROQBJWIftJ3Em9vA3peI1CW4eJ8r7WA7KSxNEjEy2Z-AGK4Y31Ac0Qg8ERh_WLoBDkRcFo3uyE8E44HG42oNPMa2BQqxO8yn9yJOsBZylTbERMxw9nasN2DV99XiUmOFY7pVmTO2uJSkWneY-40hE_utKSGh7c-w-Rv4w9ILvvJuvqzJDUapIb19Yg67gI0v4uOyS8vNarQiP_2BvSIduuIduI6orjne8ERRRpBkqMtY1kd-YTm-EF2RzLy_iZsZgYKEn92BBrPTmfu1R2KoJYmrlD0qpdLMf34D1N0IY2oIBNG1kYXB-S5TY09mY_Rs9qCQNYDX3vLKjCtJ3vm7sNGejhSv [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 267ms]
[12:26:06.371] GET https://www.facebook.com/sound_iframe.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 313ms]
```

**Problem :**
ASP.net Redirect isn't ACTUALLY Working !

Comment: ASP.net IS redirecting as you can see by the GET request on the facebook oauth url. Did you look in your browser to see what actually happens? Facebook probably threw an error. Is your facebook application set up correctly? Is your site url set to https://localhost:10010 ?

Comment: @DavidEsteves Yes, it's redirecting but as a background process not actually redirecting, facebook didn't trow errors also no js errors and my application is set up correctly